# Создание threads с порядковыми номерами

Tags: c, многопоточность

Пытаюсь создать несколько потоков, передавая каждый раз int в качестве id. 
Почему-то, вместо 0-4, выходит много других вариантов - от 1 до 5, а номера при этом могут повторяться.

Вдруг кто-то может посмотреть и сказать, где именно косячу.

```
void philosopher (void* phID)
{
    int ph = *((int*) phID);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    pthread_t phs [5];
    for(int i = 0; i< 5; i++)
    {
        sem_init(&utensils[i], 0, 1);


        pthread_create(&phs[i], NULL, (void*) &philosopher, (void*)&i);


    }
}
```

Comment: Возможно, потому что на момент запуска функции `philosopher` переменная `i` в цикле уже успевает измениться?

Comment: логично до бесконечности!
Запишите ответом? я приму

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все ваши потоки получают указатель на одну и ту же локальную переменную `i` из `main`. Если бы поток запускался мгновенно после вызова `pthread_create`, то стартовавший поток возможно успевал бы увидеть в переменной `i` правильное (свое) значение. Но такой волшебной мгновенности pthreads вам не гарантируют и не могут гарантировать. У вас получилось типичная "гонка" (race condition): что увидит стартующий поток в переменной `i` зависит от того, в какой момент он запустится и насколько "быстр" он будет по отношению к главному потоку.

Вам нужно хранить отдельную переменную для каждого потока

```
pthread_t phs[5];
int ids[5];

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
  ...
  ids[i] = i;        
  pthread_create(&phs[i], NULL, philosopher, &ids[i]);
}
```

Хотя теоретически, вы можете не заводить переменных вообще, а передавать значение `i` "как указатель"

```
void philosopher(void* phID)
{
  int ph = (int)(uintptr_t) phID;
}


...    
pthread_t phs[5];

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
  ...
  pthread_create(&phs[i], NULL, philosopher, (void *)(uintptr_t) i);
}
```

Но это очень ограничивающий способ: как только вам понадобится передать что-то еще, так снова придется возвращаться к хранимым переменным.

И что это за `(void*) &philosopher` такой у вас предается? Откуда и зачем взялось преобразование указателя на функцию к `void *`???